# D.JS MYSQL Rows Issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, discord.js

Running into an issue when trying to push a pulled query into MessageEmbed, It pushes the ID just fine but all other parts of the query do not get pushed to the message and cause a fatal error, unsure to go on to fix it after many searches and videos trying to solve it. The goal is when -pulluser @user is ran it pushes the users ID, XP, Perm, and Rank to a message embed.

Here is the code:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require(`discord.js`)
const reply = require(`../../settings/reply`)
const { createConnection } = require(`mysql`)
const mysql = require(`../../settings/mysql.js`)
const perms = require("../../settings/perms")

module.exports = {
    name: 'pulluser',
    callback: async (client, message, args) => {

        let member = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]))
      
        let con = createConnection(mysql.conInfo)

        con.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = ${member.id}`, (err, rows) => {
            
            let di = rows[0].ID 
            let xp = rows[1].XP
            let prm = rows[2].Perm
            let rnk = rows[3].Rank
            
            
            
            const pUser = new MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`Pulled User ${member}`)
                .setColor("#ff1001")
                .setDescription(`USER INFO: ID: ${di}`)
                .addField(`EXP: ${xp}`)
                .addField(`PERMISSION LEVEL: ${prm}`)
                .addField(`RANK: ${rnk}`)
                .setFooter(reply.footer.foot)
            message.channel.send(pUser)
        })


    }
}
```

The error I get is TypeError: Cannot read property 'XP' of undefined. It does this to all row requests AFTER ID. Unsure how to move forward with trying to get all the rows to be in the message.

Comment: wouldn't `rows[1]` just be `rows[0]`, as this block if an iterator over all rows (likewise for 2 & 3). And therefore `rows` probably should just be `row` for readibility. Disclaimer, I don't know js that well at all.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `row` that's returning the results is an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). So if your database is returning multiple results, then you can use it like `row[0]`, `row[2]`... `row[99]` (depending on how many results your database is returning).

In this case you receive the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'XP' of undefined

Which means your database is not returning enough rows in order for you to use the second or third row in the results. Long story short:

Replace `row[1]`, `row[2]`, `row[3]` with `row[0]`.

```
let di = rows[0].ID 
let xp = rows[0].XP
let prm = rows[0].Perm
let rnk = rows[0].Rank
```

To understand what's going on, I made you a small demonstration. Below you'll find one with only 1 array item and the second demonstration will show you what happens if you have multiple results in your array.

```js
const results = [
     {"ID": "1", "XP": "100", "Perm": 0, "Rank": "Rank 1"}
];
 
console.log(results[0].ID); // Returns "1"
console.log(results[1].XP); // Returns "undefined"
console.log(results[2].Perm); // Returns "undefined"
console.log(results[3].Rank); // Returns "undefined"
```

With multiple rows:

```js
// Example with multiple rows

const results = [
     {"ID": "1", "XP": "100", "Perm": 1, "Rank": "Rank 1"},
     {"ID": "2", "XP": "110", "Perm": 2, "Rank": "Rank 2"},
     {"ID": "3", "XP": "120", "Perm": 3, "Rank": "Rank 3"},
     {"ID": "4", "XP": "130", "Perm": 3, "Rank": "Rank 4"}
];

console.log(results[0].ID); // Returns "1" (First item in 'results')
console.log(results[1].XP); // Returns "110" (Because this is the second array item in 'results')
console.log(results[2].Perm); // Returns "3"  (Because this is the third array item in 'results')
console.log(results[3].Rank); // Returns "Rank 4" (Because this is the forth array item in 'results')
```